# Several bib.tex entries do not work in combination with biber

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, biber, bibentry

as the title says I have a problem with some of my entries that do not work out while a happy 15 others work.

My tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\title{}
\author{Me Me}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citetest.bib}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Differential geometry on exotic spheres}
An overview over the further development of exotic spheres and open problems is given in \cite{joexocurv}. In 1966, Brieskorn \cite{bries}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

This is the citetest.bib file.

```
@Article{joexocurv,
author = {Joachim, M. and Wraith, D. J.},
title = {Exotic spheres and curvature},
journaltitle = {Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
date = {2008},
volume = {45},
number = {4},
month = {10},
pages = {595-616},
}

@Article{bries,
author = {Brieskorn, E.},
title = {Beispiele zur Differentialtopologie von Singularit\"{a}ten},
journaltitle = {Inventiones Mathematicae},
date = {1966},
volume = {2},
pages = {1-14},
}
```

This is the result:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.5
INFO - Logfile is 'citetest.blg'
INFO - Reading 'citetest.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.3
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'citetest.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'citetest.bib'
```

Process exited with error(s)
Thanks in advance and kind regards!

Zonan

Comment: Welcome to the site! when I use the following file `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
hello world

\cite{krinter}, \cite{bries} and \cite{joexocurv}

\printbibliography
\end{document}` it works fine. Please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has not provided a MWE that reproduces the issue

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: once you've created a MWE, leave a comment and we can vote to reopen

Comment: Would you please describe the problem in some more detail. (What do you get, what were you expecting?) When I tried to cite the entries above in a test document, it went quite well. (You might also want to prepare a *full* MWE, i.e. one that also includes code of the document in which you cite the entries).

Comment: Ok, I created a MWE.

Comment: Your MWE works fine with me. No errors or warnings, everything as expected. The warning in your logfile (`WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.3`) suggests, that your biblatex/biber installation is a) ancient and b) incongruous. Updating your tex system should fix both.

Comment: As DG' suggests your version of `biblatex` and biber do not match, please run an update (on both; you seem to use biber 1.5 and `biblatex` 2.8 [or thereabouts], but `biblatex` 2.8 requires biber 1.8).